# making my data LOD-compatible

Tags: linked-data

I would like to incorporate the LOD (Linked Open Data) concept an app I built.

My app is a map where users search and can find points on the map, click them and get relative text and multimedia. Power users can add data via a CMS. So it's a simple digital archive.

I do not want to find LOD to put in my app. I want to publish LOD. I want my app data to be in a LOD-compatible format so others can search them and put them in their apps or use them as they want.

How do I do that? Where do I start? Please advise me about starting points and books.

While I am at it, allow me another question. I want to put a section in my app where data relative to the user's choice appears. For example, if the user searched for castles and clicked one,  this section suggests/other similar castles. Will LOD help me implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to start from the W3C about [Linked Data](http://www.w3.org/TR/ld-bp/) and how you should publish your own. I believe you will find everything you need on that paper. From their abstract:

> This document sets out a series of best practices designed to facilitate development and delivery of open government data as Linked Open Data. Linked Open Data makes the World Wide Web into a global database, sometimes refered to as the "Web of Data". Using Linked Data Principles, developers can query Linked Data from multiple sources at once and combine it without the need for a single common schema that all data shares. Prior to international data exchange standards for data on the Web, it was time consuming and difficult to build applications using traditional data management techniques. As more open government data is published on the Web, best practices are evolving too. The goal of this document is to compile the most relevant data management practices for the publication and use of of high quality data published by governments around the world as Linked Open Data.

Then, you can continue your reading by googling something like "Best practices on publishing linked data". Even the first page of the google results contains tutorials and examples that will help you.